# How to add a column and a batch_Id value to a delta table using a running pyspark streaming job?

Tags: python, spark-streaming, delta-lake

I'm trying to add a batch Id for each row in the current batch run and then write it to a delta table. A batch in my case is one CSV file with multiple values. I generate my batch Id value with a function. I can successfully add the correct batch Id when I set my streaming job to execute once but when I set it to await termination it then only executes my generate_id() function once and then adds that value as a batch Id every time I upload a CSV file to my ADLS gen2 container. I need it to execute my generate_id() function and get the new value every time it picks up a new CSV file. Please see my code below. I use a Synapse notebook to execute my code.

```
batch_id = 0 
def generate_id():
    global batch_id 
    batch_id = batch_id + 1 
    return batch_id

from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

stream = spark \
  .readStream \
  .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1) \
  .schema(customSchema) \
.csv("abfss://synapse@{storageAccountName}.dfs.core.windows.net/delta/putty/streaming_test/csv_files/") \
  .withColumn("Batch_Id",lit(generate_id())
  .writeStream \
  .outputMode("append") \
  .format("delta") \
  .option("checkpointLocation", "abfss://synapse@{storageAccountName}.dfs.core.windows.net/delta/putty/streaming_test/_checkpoints") \
  .option("mergeSchema", "true") \
  .foreachBatch(addCol) \
  .awaitTermination()
```

This is what I need:

| File Number | Value | batch_Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| File1 | Val1 | 1 |
| File1 | Val2 | 1 |
| File1 | Val3 | 1 |
| File2 | Val1 | 2 |
| File3 | Val1 | 3 |
| File3 | Val2 | 3 |

This is what I get at the moment:

| File Number | Value | batch_Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| File1 | Val1 | 1 |
| File1 | Val2 | 1 |
| File1 | Val3 | 1 |
| File2 | Val1 | 1 |
| File3 | Val1 | 1 |
| File3 | Val2 | 1 |

I've also tried to use the foreachbatch function but that doesn't seem to work:

```
def addCol(df, epochId):
    df.withColumn("Batch_Id",lit(generate_id()))

stream = spark \
  .readStream \
  .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1) \
  .schema(customSchema) \
.csv("abfss://synapse@{storageAccountName}.dfs.core.windows.net/delta/putty/streaming_test/csv_files/") \
  .writeStream \
  .outputMode("append") \
  .format("delta") \
  .option("checkpointLocation", "abfss://synapse@{storageAccountName}.dfs.core.windows.net/delta/putty/streaming_test/_checkpoints") \
  .option("mergeSchema", "true") \
  .foreachBatch(addCol) \
  .toTable("patients")
  .awaitTermination()
```

This is the error that I get when I run my code. I'm not sure what it means:

```
AnalysisException: The input source(foreachBatch) is different from the table patients's data source provider(delta).
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/streaming.py", line 1563, in toTable
    return self._sq(self._jwrite.toTable(tableName))

  File "/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(

  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 117, in deco
    raise converted from None

pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: The input source(foreachBatch) is different from the table patients's data source provider(delta).
```

I'm new to spark streaming but it feels like something like this should be possible when I keep my streaming job active. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try using `map()` or `mapPartition()` function to solve this usecase.
Something like below might work in your case.

You can call your generate Batch Id function for each row object in your dataframe.

```
df.mapPartitions(iterator => {
    val resultList = new List
    entityIterator.foreach(rowObject => {
        val batchId = generateBatchId()
        val fileNumber = rowObject.getAs("fileNumber")
        val value = rowObject.getAs("value")
        val rowData = Row(fileNumber,value,batchId)
        itr.add(rowData)
       }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate you trying to help we managed to solve it with a merge and for each batch function.

Answer (score 0):

```
deltadf = DeltaTable.forName(spark,table_name)

def mergeToDF(microBatchDf, batchid):
  microBatchDf = microBatchDf.withColumn("Batch_ID",increment_id()).withColumn("Test_ID",lit(test_id))
  (deltadf.alias("target").merge(
     source=microBatchDf.alias("source"),
     condition = f"source.RECID = target.RECID"
  ).whenMatchedUpdateAll()
   .whenNotMatchedInsertAll()
   .execute())

spark.readStream.format("csv") \
  .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1) \
  .schema(table_schema) \
  .load(f"data_lake_path/{table_name}") \
  .writeStream.format("delta") \
  .outputMode("append") \
  .foreachBatch(mergeToDF) \
  .option("mergeSchema",True) \
  .option("checkpointLocation","data_lake_path/_checkpoints") \
  .start(save_path)
```

Comment: Realizing you are answering your own question here, but consider updating your answer and adding an explanation of your solution. A little bit of a description can help others who come across the same issue.